# How to remove line breaks and empty lines from String

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, line-breaks

I am trying to run a mapreduce job on hadoop which reads the fifth entry of a tab delimited file (fifth entry are user reviews) and then do some sentiment analysis and word count on them.

However, as you know with user reviews, they usually include line breaks and empty lines. My code iterates through the words of each review to find keywords and check sentiment if keyword is found.

The problem is as the code iterates through the review, it gives me `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException` Error because of these line breaks and empty lines in one review.

I have tried using `replaceAll("\r", " ")` and `replaceAll("\n", " ")` to no avail.

I have also tried `if(tokenizer.countTokens() == 2){
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());}
else {
 }`

also to no avail. Below is my code:

```
public class KWSentiment_Mapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
ArrayList<String> keywordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> posWordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> tokensList = new ArrayList<String>();
int e;

@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String[] line = value.toString().split("\t");
    String Review = line[4].replaceAll("[\\-\\+\\\\)\\.\\(\"\\{\\$\\^:,]", "").toLowerCase();

    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(Review);

    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        // 1- first read the review line and store the tokens in an arraylist, 2-
        // iterate through review to check for KW if found
        // 3-check if there's PosWord near (upto +3 and -2)
        // 4- setWord & context.write 5- null the review line arraylist
        String CompareString = tokenizer.nextToken();

        tokensList.add(CompareString);
    }
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < tokensList.size(); i++)

    {

        for (int j = 0; j < keywordsList.size(); j++) {
            boolean flag = false;

            if (tokensList.get(i).startsWith(keywordsList.get(j)) == true) {

                for (int e = Math.max(0, i - 2); e < Math.min(tokensList.size(), i + 4); e++) {

                    if (posWordsList.contains(tokensList.get(e))) {

                        word.set(keywordsList.get(j));
                        context.write(word, one);
                        flag = true;

                        break; // breaks out of e loop }}
                    }
                }
            }
            if (flag)
                break;
        }
    }
    tokensList.clear();
}
```

}

Expected results are such that: 
Take these two cases of reviews where error occurs:

Case 1: "Beautiful and spacious!
I highly recommend this place and great host."

Case 2: "The place in general was really silent but we didn't feel stayed.

Aside from this, the bathroom is big and the shower is really nice but there  problem. "

The system should read the whole review as one line and iterate through the words in it. However, it just stops as it finds a line break or an empty line as in case 2.
Case 1 should be read such as: "Beautiful and spacious! I highly recommend this place and great host."

Case 2 should be:"The place in general was really silent but we didn't feel stayed. Aside from this, the bathroom is big and the shower is really nice but there problem. "

I am running out of time and would really appreciate help here.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it is not clear, here is a sample of the text file the system is reading.  >1302369 134958657 8417768 Anon "Beautiful and spacious!
I highly recommend this place and great host."  >1401724 87802333 82672125 Anonym "Since our train arrived around 6:30 am, we let Lia know if we could leave our luggage and she kindly said yes. We arrived at 6:45 am at her

Aside from this, the bathroom is big and the shower is really nice but there is a sign isn't described."

Comment: Please add sample input into the question itself with appropriate formatting.

Answer (score 0):

So, I hope I am understanding what what you are trying to do....
If I am reading what you have above correctly, the value of 'value' passed into your map function above contains the delimited value that you would like to parse the user reviews out of.  If that is the case, I believe we can make use of the escaping functionality in the opencsv library using tabs as your delimiting character instead of commas to correctly populate the user review field:
http://opencsv.sourceforge.net

In this example we are reading one line from the input that is passed in and parsing it into 'columns' base on the tab character and placing the results in the 'nextLine' array.  This will allow us to use the escaping functionality of the CSVReader without reading an actual file and instead using the value of the text passed into your map function.

```
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(value.toString());
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader, '\t', '\"', '\\', 0);

        String [] nextLine = csvReader.readNext();
        if(nextLine != null && nextLine.length >= 5) {
           // Do some stuff
        }
```

In the example that you pasted above, I think even that split("\n") will be problematic as tabs within a user review split into two results in the result in addition to new lines being treated as new records.  But, both of these characters are legal as long as they are inside a quoted value (as they should be in a properly escaped file and as they are in your example).  CSVReader should handle all of these.

Comment: I missed the tab delimited part in your original question.  I have updated my answer.  I hope this helps.  I would for sure save using CSVWriter with the default behavior if that is option.  Reading and writing will be much easier in this case.

Comment: Hi @Christopher Thanks for your reply.  I am sorry. It seems I misunderstood your question. The input file I am trying to read is saved in HDFS. This program is for running a hadoop mapreduce job. Thus, why the CSV reader won't work in this case

Comment: It looks like your file content that you added as a comment above is tab delimited with " quoting character.  So, I think the above example code should fix your problem.

Comment: I changed the title of the question as it seems misleading I suppose. Apologies for that. As mentioned in my above comment, the input file the system is reading is saved and read from HDFS line by line. That is, each line of the tab delimited file is first read as a whole. In my code above, these two lines are important String[] line = value.toString().split("\t"); 
    String Review = line[4].toLowerCase();   @Christopher Thanks for the modification & for bringing my attention to the ambiguity of the question. I modified the question now.

Comment: @R.A  I have updated again.  I hope I am understanding what you are doing now?

Comment: Thanks very much again. The "Text" in the KWSentiment_Mapper function is passed to the map function in which the user review is being parsed. I will try the above indeed. Just one question, does my input file need to be saved as CSV to be able to use CSVReader?

Comment: @R.A you do not need to save anything with this example.  The parsing of the line is all done over the StringReader object, which is initialized from the text value passed in and exists in memory.
I have added another couple of sentences to the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Validate each line at the start of the `map` method, so that you know `line[4]` exists and isn't null.

```
if (value == null || value.toString == null) {
    return;
}

String[] line = value.toString().split("\t");
if (line == null || line.length() < 5 || line[4] == null) {
    return;
}
```

As for line breaks, you'll need to show some sample input. By default MapReduce passes each line into the `map` method independently, so if you do want to read multiple lines as one message, you'll have to write a custom `InputSplit`, or pre-format your data so that all data for each review is on the same line.